# Sorting an array list of intervals?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, intervals

I have a set of intervals S contained in an array list. How can I sort those arrays based on the left or right end-points?

For instance, if I had the following intervals [1,3],[1,2],[2,5],[3,3] how can I sort them based on their left end-points?

I am aware of the different sorting algorithms like sequential sort, insertion sort and merge sort, but I'm clueless on how to sort a set of intervals.

Any help or hints to guide me in the right direction will be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is missing a lot of information. The code you've been trying and the programming language you're using for example

Comment: Doing this in java and I know how to implement simple sorting algorithms to sort an array of integers like [1,4,6,2,3], but I am clueless on how to sort a set of intervals based on their left or right end points.

Answer (score 0):

Try radix sort, it will help you if all values are single digit only it is very easy to implement.

Comment: What do you mean by all the values are "single digit". Given an array list that stores a set of integers like [1,4],[1,2],[1,5],[3,6],[5,8],[3,4] how can I sort these intervals based on solely their left or right endpoints?

Comment: Single digit means, one letter digit like 1, 2, 3,... try to apply radix sort on first element an do sort and then second element and sort. For single digit it is very easy to apply.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this command

```java
intervals.sort((i1, i2) -> Integer.compare(i1.start, i2.start));
```

Hopefully you will get it correct based on starting points or if you want to sort based on end points just compare `(i1.end,i2.end)`.